Using regex to match multiple substring instances from one string
I'm using Qt's QtRegularExpression class and I want to extract multiple substring instances that matches the expression of paired ()s with anything inside from a single string input with multiple occurrences of that pattern
I'm pretty sure that my regex is correct as "\\([^)]+\\)"
My current code looks like this
QString example1 = "(val1, val2)";
QString example2 = "(val1, val2), (val3, val4)";
QString example3 = "(val1, val2), (val3, val4), (val5, val6)";
QRegularExpression re("\\([^)]+\\)");
QRegularExpressionMatch match;
QStringList matchList;
match = re.match(example1);
matchList = match.capturedTexts();
qDebug() << "Example 1: " << matchList << Qt::endl;
match = re.match(example2);
matchList = match.capturedTexts();
qDebug() << "Example 2: " << matchList << Qt::endl;
match = re.match(example3);
matchList = match.capturedTexts();
qDebug() << "Example 3: " << matchList << Qt::endl;

Expected output:
Example 1: QList("(val1, val2)")
Example 2: QList("(val1, val2)", "(val3, val4)")
Example 3: QList("(val1, val2)", "(val3, val4)", "(val5, val6)")

Actual output:
Example 1: QList("(val1, val2)")
Example 2: QList("(val1, val2)")
Example 3: QList("(val1, val2)")

If I change the regex to "(\\([^)]+\\))" matchList becomes QList("(val1, val2)", "(val1, val2)"), the first value gets duplicated. Each pair of parantheses I add on the outside adds another duplicate of the first match. I don't understand why this happens
Is this a missunderstanding with how the match() and capturedTexts() functions work? If so what's another way I could go about this?
As a sidenote, is there an easy way to discard the parentheses after/while matching the strings?

I don't understand the down votes, so I cannot offer suggestions for improvement. To me, this question looks better written than the one it's a duplicate of (and the duplicate has no down votes).

Like almost every question about regular expressions on this site, this search is utterly trivial if you don’t use a regular expression.
